# Ruby group non-zero numbers and sequential times

Tags: arrays, ruby, grouping, nmatrix

I have an array of items like so: `[DateTime, value]`. I want to group the items which satisfy the following conditions:

- A sequence of 3 or more items
- Items contain values which are > 0
- times are sequential (increasing by 1 second)

I want to get the indices of the start and end of the sequences that meet those conditions.

E.g.

```
[ 
[today 10:00:00, 1],
[today 10:00:01, 1],
[today 10:00:02, 1],
[today 10:00:03, 0],
[today 10:00:04, 1],
[today 10:00:05, 1],
[today 10:00:16, 1],
[today 10:00:17, 1],
]
```

Should return:

```
[ [0,2] ]
```

I had a look at [Daru](https://github.com/SciRuby/daru) and [NMatrix](http://sciruby.com/nmatrix/docs/NMatrix.html) but I couldn't figure out how to do sequential comparisons to do what I want.

Now I've just got a big loop that does a lot of comparisons - is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "times are sequential". It is not clear.

Comment: Does "sequential" mean they are _exactly_ 1 second apart?

Comment: @sawa, stefan Sorry, yes, sequential means times are 1 second apart.

Comment: @Stefan edited to defined 'sequential'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = Time.now
a = [
  [t + 0, 1],
  [t + 1, 1],
  [t + 2, 1],
  [t + 3, 0],
  [t + 4, 1],
  [t + 5, 1],
  [t + 16, 1],
  [t + 17, 1],
]

a
.each_with_index
.chunk_while{
  |(x, i), (y, j)|
  x[1].positive? and
  y[1].positive? and
  x[0].to_i.next == y[0].to_i
}
.select{|chunk| chunk.length >= 3}
.map{|chunk| [chunk.first[1], chunk.last[1]]}
# => [[0, 2]]
```

Comment: 1) the indices `i` and `j` from `each_with_index` are never used, 2) you shouldn't use `and` as a substitute for `&&`

Comment: @Stefan I know I could use `_`, but I used `i`, `j` for clarity. You can easily see that they are indices. That helps later when reading `chunk.first[1], chunk.last[1]`. It tells what `[1]` means. And there is nothing wrong with using `and`. People tend to want to distinguish control sequences from things that return values, but that idea does not make sense in Ruby. Every expression in Ruby has a return value. And using ordinary words like `and` is easier to read in contexts like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = Time.now
arr = [[t+ 0, 1], [t+ 1, 1], [t+ 2, 1], [t+ 3, 0], [t+ 4, 1], [t+ 5, 1], [t+16, 1],
       [t+18, 1], [t+19, 1], [t+20, 1], [t+21, 1], [t+30, 1]]
  #=> [[2018-11-06 10:11:52 -0800, 1], [2018-11-06 10:11:53 -0800, 1],...,
  #    [2018-11-06 10:12:22 -0800, 1]]

arr.each_index.
    slice_when { |i,j| arr[i].last.zero? || arr[i-1].last.zero? ||
      (arr[i].first - arr[i-1].first > 1) }.
    each_with_object([]) { |a,b| b << [a.first, a.last] if a.last-a.first >= 2 }
  #=> [[0, 2], [7, 10]]
```

[Emumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (new in MRI v2.2) is closely related to [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) (new in MRI v2.3), which @sawa used in his answer. Generally, if one can be used, the other is an alternative.

To support earlier versions of Ruby one could use [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) (new in MRI v1.9.2).

```
arr.each_index.
    slice_before { |i| i > 0 &&
      (arr[i].last.zero? || arr[i-1].last.zero? || (arr[i].first - arr[i-1].first > 1)) }.
    each_with_object([]) { |a,b| b << [a.first, a.last] if a.last-a.first >= 2 }
```

Note the intermediate calculation:

```
enum = arr.each_index.slice_before {|i| i > 0 &&
  (arr[i].last.zero? || arr[i-1].last.zero? || (arr[i].first - arr[i-1].first > 1)) }
  #=> => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x0000000001948d50>:each>
enum.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11]]
```

(The return value is the same when using `slice_when`.) If preferred, the clause

```
each_with_object([]) { |a,b| b << [a.first, a.last] if a.last-a.first >= 2 }
```

could be replaced with a two-pass alternative:

```
select { |a| a.last - a.first >= 2 }.map { |a| [a.first, a.last] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and covering different ruby versions!